# Get list of published items on arcgis server

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to query the list of all features service layers and map layers from ArcGIS Server via ArcGIS javascript?

Comment: There should be a getcapabilities function that list the services and layers present in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this information via a REST request against the ArcGIS Server API. Something like this:

```
esriRequest({
  url: serviceUrl,
  content: {
    "f": "json"
  },
  callbackParamName: "callback"
}).then(function(response) {

  // do stuff here

});
```

[Full demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/a4467wua/).

Comment: Is it possible to drill down to list and sort the feature layers by Geometry Type? i am trying to do a look alike version of Database Connection in Catalog tree of ArcMap into web form? Is there other ways to display?

Comment: If you had a developer who knows what they're doing, yes they could make the proper REST calls, using the method I am showing above, to use a Tree widget (like jsTree https://www.jstree.com/demo/) to build a tree-style control of the services.

Comment: can you show me some examples?